# Perpendicular Training Vectors SVM

Tags: machine-learning, svm

Claim: If we are training a hard-margin SVM on a set of perpendicular training vectors which can either be classified as "positive" or "negative," will every training vector end up being a support vector if the data is linearly classifiable?

I can't seem to come up with a counterexample to this claim. Any ideas?

Comment: Applying an orthogonal transformation you can assume that the training vectors are aligned to the coordinate vectors. You can do this since an orthogonal transformation is linear and doesn't change distances. Then, you can solve [the optimization problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_vector_machine#Hard-margin) explicitly, since all constraints depend only of one variable. To get the smallest $\|w\|$ you make all inequalities equalities. So, all training vectors lie on the margin hyperplanes.

Comment: What if you take a SVM with a particular decision boundary, and then add one more point that is already correctly classified by that SVM to the training set.  How will that affect the resulting SVM?